# Agrupar segun descripcion y distintos codigos

Tags: sql, sql-server, agrupación

le comento.
Tego una tabla de productos, la cual muestra informacion de cantidades disponibles. El asunto es que necesito poder agrupar estos productos por descripcion, pero hay productos los cuales tienen mismo codigo, solo que difieren en dos caracteres, por ejemplo, y otros que son codigos unicos.

(**TODO ESTO ESTA EN SQL SERVER**)

Aqui un ejemplo de la tabla:

| Codigo | Descripcion | Cantidad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2251B003AC | PRINTER AF-03 | 20 |
| 2251B003AD | PRINTER AF-03 | 1 |
| 8524B003AA | 33 TONER BLACK | 0 |
| 8524B003BA | 33 TONER BLACK | 1 |
| 0834V787 | BACKLIT FILM 36ZF | 6 |
| 0452C001AA | CARTRIDGE 071 | 11 |

Y el resultado que necesito obtener

| Codigo | Descripcion | Cantidad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2251B003 | PRINTER AF-03 | 21 |
| 8524B003 | 33 TONER BLACK | 1 |
| 0834V787 | BACKLIT FILM 36ZF | 6 |
| 0452C001AA | CARTRIDGE 071 | 11 |

Si se dan cuenta, por ejemplo en 'PRINTER AF-03', como los codigos de ambos productos son identicos, a excepcion de los dos ultimos caracteres (AC, AD), solo necesito extrater el codigo en comun entre ellos y sumar sus cantidades, dejando un unico codigo (2251B003)...

El detalle, como explicaba antes, es que hay codigos que son unicos y por lo cual no puedo aplicar, por ejemplo, un `SUBSTRING`, ya que de primera en eso casos unicos, se debe conservar el codigo tal cual.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Y cual es la lógica para decir que unos se tienen que cortar y otros no?

Comment: La idea es dejar agrupados todos por descripcion, ya que eso estan solicitando y los codigos que estan 'repetidos', como indicaba mas arriba, que queden acortados.
Por ejemplo, los dos registros `8524B003AA` y `8524B003BA` queden en un solo registro sumando sus cantidades y que el codigo resultante sea solo `8524B003`, ya que estos dos comparten ese codigo y solo difiere en la dos ultimas letras.,
El detalle, es que esto no ocurre con otros codigos.

Comment: Y como magicamente nosotros podemos saber que codigos tenes que acortar y cuales no, segun que reglas? por ahora, es imposible decirte algo...

Comment: En resumen, acortar los codigos donde la descripcion se repita (sorry lo enredado, pero es lo que me pidieron y estoy igual de confuso)

Comment: @Oriel justamente ese es el problema, como no todos los códigos tienen esos dos últimos dígitos repetidos, se tendría que formular alguna clase de métrica para saber cuándo se debe de agrupar, por ejemplo, si coinciden más del 50% de caracteres entonces agrupar, se me ocurre; pero ello, tienes que decirlo tú.

Comment: "pero es lo que me pidieron " es un requerimiento de donde trabajas, y quien debe definirlo es quien genero esos codigos, y quien sabe como se guardan, y quien sabe en que casos se acortan y en cuales no. Esta, no es una pregunta para SO, es una pregunta para quien define tus sistemas...

Comment: Por ejemplo, los códigos `2251B003AC` y `2251B003AD` se acortaron a `2251B003` en vez de `2251B003A` ¿Cuál fue la lógica? Si hay que acortar los que terminan en doble consonante ¿Por qué no se acortó `0452C001AA`?

Comment: @LuisCazares, es porque `0452C001AA` tiene un solo registro con una sola descripcion, pero `2251B003AC` y `2251B003AD` tienen descipciones identicas (`PRINTER AF-03`), por eso es que se agrupan esos dos registros en uno solo con un nuevo codigo, que seria el mismo que comparten `2251B003`

Comment: Ah ves.. tenes una logica, que hasta ahora no habias explicado.. No vas a poder hacer esto con un query, porque implicaria contar, ir para adelante y para atras con las cadenas.. necesitas un proceso

Comment: @gbianchi, pense que en las tablas de ejemplo lo habia dejado claro, me disculpo.
Me perdi con lo del proceso.

Answer (score 0):

Si el patrón que definen los códigos repetidos es la parte izquierda, la solución puede ser tan simple como esto:

```
create table codigos
             (
             codigo      varchar(20)
           , Descripcion varchar(100)
           , Cantidad    int
             );
go

Insert into codigos(codigo
                  , Descripcion
                  , Cantidad)
values
       ( '2251B003AC', 'PRINTER AF-03', 20 ),
       ( '2251B003AD', 'PRINTER AF-03', 1 ),
       ( '8524B003AA', '33 TONER BLACK', 0 ),
       ( '8524B003BA', '33 TONER BLACK', 1 ),
       ( '0834V787', 'BACKLIT FILM 36ZF', 6 ),
       ( '0452C001AA', 'CARTRIDGE 071', 11 );
GO
```

Primero buscamos y contamos los códigos que son únicos o no. En función de que sean únicos o no en el segundo cte extraemos sus datos. Y en la salida agrupamos.

```
With r2
     As (Select Left(Codigo, Len(Codigo) - 2) as Codigo
              , Count(1) as esUnico
                From codigos
                Group by Left(Codigo, Len(Codigo) - 2)),
     r3
     As (Select case
                    when r2.esUnico = 1 then codigos.codigo
                else r2.Codigo
                End as codigo
              , Descripcion
              , Cantidad
                From codigos
                     left join r2 on Left(codigos.Codigo,
                Len(codigos.Codigo) - 2) = r2.codigo)
     SELECT r3.codigo
          , r3.Descripcion
          , Sum(CANTIDAD) AS CANTIDAD
            FROM r3
            GROUP BY r3.codigo
                   , r3.Descripcion;
```

[image: Resultado]

Como no veo claro un criterio para ordenar, no lo he establecido.

Answer (score 0):

Dejo una solución alternativa. La lógica sigue siendo extraña, pero es algo que se debe de revisar con las personas que solicitaron eso.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT( DISTINCT codigo) > 1
            THEN LEFT( MIN( codigo), LEN( MIN( codigo))- 2)
            ELSE MIN(codigo) END AS codigo,
        Descripcion,
        SUM(Cantidad) AS Cantidad
FROM codigos
GROUP BY Descripcion;
```